# How to get lid state using linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I can read the status of my laptop lid by reading `/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state` file. Now I want to read it from kernel module.

I found the source file `drivers/acpi/button.c` in kernel source. But still I didn't understand how to use it. It exporting `acpi_lid_notifier_register, acpi_lid_notifier_unregiste` and `acpi_lid_open` functions.

How to write a module for lid state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`acpi_lid_open`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/acpi/button.c#L236) returns 0 (closed), 1 (open), or a negative error number (unsupported).

To use the notifier, you would define a callback function and a notifier block in your module:

```c
static int yourmodule_lid_notify(struct notifier_block *nb, unsigned long val, void *unused) {
    // Whatever you wanted to do here
}
static struct notifier_block lid_notifier;

// Somewhere in a function, likely your module init function:
lid_notifier.notifier_call = yourmodule_lid_notify;
if (acpi_lid_notifier_register(&lid_notifier)) {
    // TODO: Handle the failure here
}

// TODO: Unregister the notifier when your module is unloaded:
acpi_lid_notifier_unregister(&lid_notifier);
```

Comment: getting error: `include/acpi/acpi_drivers.h:86:32: error: unknown type name ‘acpi_handle’`

Comment: So don't include that file. Include `<acpi/button.h>`, which appears to be the public API only.