# Watch events after laptop lid open

Tags: linux-kernel, acpi

## Context

- Hardware

  - DELL - Inspiron 13-5378
  - Touchscreen
  - 2-in-1 - its hinge supports 360 degrees movement
- Operating System

  - Ubuntu GNU/Linux 19.04
  - Kernel `5.0.0-29-generic`

## Problem statement

After closing the lid, it suspends.  Afterward, when opening it, the keyboard and mouse stop working.  Keyboard backlight works and shine. (as they freeze I'm unable to log in)

**Workaround**: I do flip the lid backward (about 180 degrees), the keyboard backlight goes off.  Then, I get the lid back again, the backlights turn on, and keyboard and mouse start working, seeming they were restarted.

## Questions

1. How can I programmatically monitor the events in my laptop after the lid gets opened? (kernel module or ACPI API or something else)
2. How can I hook a function to automatically restart the keyboard without the need to do it mechanically by myself? (supposing this is a quick and dirty solution)

## Details

- [lshw](https://pastebin.com/MYd8zqkk)

```
darkstar
    description: Laptop
    product: Inspiron 13-5378 (0740)
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    serial: XXXXXXX
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=docking family=Inspiron sku=0740 uuid=66666666-6666-6666-6666-666666666666
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 07RVYG
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A01
       serial: /xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1.26.0
          date: 07/17/2018
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 15MiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 3d
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
             product: SF4641G8CK8IWGKSEG
             vendor: AMD
             physical id: 0
             serial: 05FDBC88
             slot: DIMM A
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 41
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 128KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 42
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 512KiB
          capacity: 512KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 43
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 4MiB
          capacity: 4MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 44
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 2976MHz
          capacity: 3500MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
     ...
  *-battery
       product: DELL 8YPRW79
       vendor: LG
       physical id: 1
       version: 01/20/2017
       serial: xxxx
       slot: Sys. Battery Bay
       capacity: 41990mWh
       configuration: voltage=11,4V
```

- [dmesg](https://pastebin.com/AhfWvUT9) (this content corresponds to kernel logs before and after I close and open the lid; I did `dmesg --clear` before closing lid)

```
[145814.051699] kauditd_printk_skb: 8 callbacks suppressed
[145814.051704] audit: type=1107 audit(1569204467.676:487): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145814.055243] audit: type=1107 audit(1569204467.680:488): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145814.065506] dell_wmi: Unknown key with type 0x0000 and code 0xe070 pressed
[145817.991579] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[145817.991580] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[145817.999683] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[145818.001834] OOM killer disabled.
[145818.001835] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[145818.003151] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[145818.003872] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from jkljçkl by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[145818.028521] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[145818.028607] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[145818.413570] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[145818.457081] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[145818.461800] ACPI: EC: event blocked
[145818.461801] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
[145818.461802] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[145818.461854] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[145818.462271] IRQ 124: no longer affine to CPU1
[145818.463299] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[145818.465628] IRQ 125: no longer affine to CPU2
[145818.467181] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[145818.469299] IRQ 123: no longer affine to CPU3
[145818.469309] IRQ 145: no longer affine to CPU3
[145818.470330] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[145818.474859] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[145818.474936] ACPI: EC: EC started
[145818.474937] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[145818.480831] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[145818.480901] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[145818.480902] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[145818.481500]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[145818.481656] CPU1 is up
[145818.481683] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[145818.482219]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[145818.482543] CPU2 is up
[145818.482569] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[145818.483053]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[145818.483230] CPU3 is up
[145818.487049] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[145818.514858] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[145818.557229] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[145818.557958] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[145818.759867] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 8909
[145818.804002] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[145818.869996] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[145818.943211] atkbd serio0: Spurious ACK on isa0060/serio0. Some program might be trying to access hardware directly.
[145818.949020] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[145818.949021] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[145818.949023] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[145818.949035] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[145818.949056] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[145818.958270] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[145818.958272] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[145818.958273] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[145818.958311] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[145818.958530] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[145819.040909] restoring control 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000101/10/5
[145819.040909] restoring control 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000101/12/11
[145819.064208] ACPI Error: Thread 2025434880 cannot release Mutex [PATM] acquired by thread 2208450176 (20181213/exmutex-382)
[145819.064213] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_Q66]
[145819.064214] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q66]
[145819.064215] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66, AE_AML_NOT_OWNER (20181213/psparse-531)
[145819.083983] usb 1-8: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[145819.360083] usb 1-6: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[145819.636082] usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[145819.786923] acpi LNXPOWER:13: Turning OFF
[145819.786999] acpi LNXPOWER:12: Turning OFF
[145819.787063] acpi LNXPOWER:11: Turning OFF
[145819.787128] acpi LNXPOWER:10: Turning OFF
[145819.787192] acpi LNXPOWER:0f: Turning OFF
[145819.787257] acpi LNXPOWER:0e: Turning OFF
[145819.787319] acpi LNXPOWER:0d: Turning OFF
[145819.787386] acpi LNXPOWER:0c: Turning OFF
[145819.787447] acpi LNXPOWER:0b: Turning OFF
[145819.787511] acpi LNXPOWER:0a: Turning OFF
[145819.787577] acpi LNXPOWER:09: Turning OFF
[145819.787639] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
[145819.787702] acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
[145819.787765] acpi LNXPOWER:06: Turning OFF
[145819.787848] acpi LNXPOWER:05: Turning OFF
[145819.787911] acpi LNXPOWER:04: Turning OFF
[145819.787977] acpi LNXPOWER:03: Turning OFF
[145819.788040] acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
[145819.788105] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
[145819.788171] acpi LNXPOWER:00: Turning OFF
[145819.788316] OOM killer enabled.
[145819.788316] Restarting tasks ... 
[145819.792957] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin
[145819.792962] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x302 build 0x3e8, firmware rome 0x302 build 0x111
[145819.794419] done.
[145819.847624] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000302.bin
[145819.878499] PM: suspend exit
[145819.882103] ish-hid {----}: [hid-ish]: enum_devices_done OK, num_hid_devices=4
[145820.008363] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205368.523:489): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/24" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145820.008367] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205368.527:490): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145820.008369] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205368.527:491): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/24" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145820.008371] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205368.527:492): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/24" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145820.008373] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205368.527:493): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/24" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145820.010146] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205368.531:494): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145820.015942] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205368.535:495): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145820.016323] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205368.539:496): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/24" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145820.017625] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205368.539:497): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145820.020011] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205368.543:498): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/24" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145821.434818] ACPI Error: Thread 2025068416 cannot release Mutex [PATM] acquired by thread 2034327040 (20181213/exmutex-382)
[145821.434846] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_Q66]
[145821.434848] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q66]
[145821.434849] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66, AE_AML_NOT_OWNER (20181213/psparse-531)
[145825.141711] kauditd_printk_skb: 12 callbacks suppressed
[145825.141713] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205373.663:511): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145825.144497] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205373.667:512): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145825.145743] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205373.667:513): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/25" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145825.146973] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205373.667:514): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145825.149162] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205373.671:515): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145825.154559] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205373.675:516): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145825.161756] wlp1s0: authenticate with 66:66:66:66:66:66
[145825.211066] wlp1s0: send auth to 66:66:66:66:66:66 (try 1/3)
[145825.212169] wlp1s0: authenticated
[145825.212324] wlp1s0: associating with AP with corrupt beacon and probe response
[145825.216023] wlp1s0: associate with 66:66:66:66:66:66 (try 1/3)
[145825.217998] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 66:66:66:66:66:66 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[145825.220184] wlp1s0: associated
[145825.224015] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
[145825.227182] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205373.747:517): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/25" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145825.496111] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205374.019:518): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/25" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145825.506084] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205374.027:519): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/25" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145825.507568] audit: type=1107 audit(1569205374.027:520): pid=953 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.16" mask="receive" pid=15183 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=986 peer_label="unconfined"
                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[145826.790364] dell_wmi: Unknown key with type 0x0000 and code 0xe070 pressed
[145829.638333] dell_wmi: Unknown key with type 0x0000 and code 0xe070 pressed
```

I have found "[How to get lid state using linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30513745/716079)
", but I have not tested it yed.

Comment: You could ssh from another laptop on the network (assuming when you close the lid, network stays ON).

Comment: When I say "monitor" I mean to insert a piece of code that gets raised when the lid events happens.  Maybe something related to kbus (IDK).  I will clarify this point in my question.

Comment: You need to read ACPI tables for the starter.

Comment: `dell_wmi: Unknown key with type 0x0000 and code 0xe070 pressed` hmm, seems the driver doesn't know what to do with this. Try to add your key to the array `dell_wmi_keymap_type_0000`. Example (it though adds to another array nearby): https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/platform/x86/dell-wmi.c?id=842b854459462a6065d3595f8485601800bbf5d3